# How to return json boolean value of true/false in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

this script outputs the wrong json variable

script;

```
import scrapy


class MastodonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mastodonsocial'
    start_urls = ['https://mastodon.social/explore']

    def parse(self, response):
        for users in response.css('div.directory__card'):
            yield {
                'name': users.css('strong.p-name::text').get(),
                'alternate_names': '',
                'gender': '',
                'category': '',
                'description': users.css('p::text').get(),
                'fediverse': users.css('span::text').get(),
                'link': users.css('a.directory__card__bar__name').attrib['href'],
                'image': users.css('img.u-photo').attrib['src'],
                'language': '',
                'region': '',
                'user': true,
                'group' : false,
                'creator': false,
                'companyOrganization': false,
                'project': false,
                'applicationSoftware': false,

            }
        for nextpage in response.css('span.next'):
            next_page = nextpage.css('a').attrib['href']
            if next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

output (json);

```
[
{
    "name": "name", 
    "alternate_names": "", 
    "gender": "", 
    "category": "", 
    "description": null, 
    "fediverse": "@username@mastodon.online", 
    "link": "https://mastodon.online/users/$number", 
    "image": "https://files.mastodon.online/accounts/avatars/image.png", 
    "language": "", 
    "region": "", 
    "user": "true", 
    "group": "false", 
    "creator": "false", 
    "companyOrganization": "false", 
    "project": "false", 
    "applicationSoftware": "false"
  }
]
```

the boolean variable is supposed to be without quotation marks (`"user": true,` not `"user": "true",`)

I tried just removing the quotation marks in the script but it ends up failing to execute. is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: `true` is special both in [Python](http://python.org/) and in [JSON](http://json.org/). I recommend reading documentation of both, and paper books about both. And [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) seems to have some documentation. It is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) (see [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy)...) and you could study and improve its source code

Comment: I had to change it to python compatible boolean variable (`True/False`) to convert it to json. that works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it to python compatible boolean variable (`True/False`) to convert it to json. that works.

solution;

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for users in response.css('div.directory__card'):
            yield {
                'name': users.css('strong.p-name::text').get(),
                'alternate_names': '',
                'gender': '',
                'category': '',
                'description': users.css('p::text').get(),
                'fediverse': users.css('span::text').get(),
                'link': users.css('a.directory__card__bar__name').attrib['href'],
                'image': users.css('img.u-photo').attrib['src'],
                'language': '',
                'region': '',
                'user': True,
                'group' : False,
                'creator': False,
                'companyOrganization': False,
                'project': False,
                'applicationSoftware': False,
```